# it's possible to install rest-proxy confluent in apache kafka cluster kafka version 2.0.0

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, kafka-rest

I would integrate kafka-rest-proxy confluent solution with apache kafka 2.0.0

Could some one explain how I install only kafka rest proxy for my cluster with 3 nodes kafka and 3 znodes ?

Answer (score 1):

All of the Confluent tools work with Apache Kafka.

There is no individual download of the REST Proxy, so you would have to use Docker or download the full Confluent platform.

If not using Docker, you can find the `kafka-rest.properties` in the `etc/kafka-rest` folder, and so you would edit it with at least the bootstrap servers.

Find other [config options here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/config.html)

Then run this to start it from the extract Confluent platform download

```
./bin/kafka-rest-start ./etc/kafka-rest/kafka-rest.properties
```